# Using angularjs with medium editor

Tags: angularjs, medium-editor

I find the angular-medium-editor on Github but cannot figure out how to use it, here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cDtrmqd8RxGmYA0hKKur?p=preview). Please help me point out what's wrong there. Thank you.

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.21"></script>
<script src="httpshttp://dfimg.com/medium-editor/dist/js/medium-editor.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thijsw/angular-medium-editor/master/dist/angular-medium-editor.js"></script>
...
<h1 ng-model="name" medium-editor options='{"placeholder": "Enter a title", "disableToolbar": true, "forcePlainText": true, "disableReturn": true}'>name name</h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I forget to specify the module dependencies, so just adding

`"angular-medium-editor"`

when declaring your module will do.

Answer (score 0):

I think using above solution will not give you clear picture of using medium editor with angular so [look at](http://www.frustrateddevelopers.com/2015/10/how-to-use-medium-editor-with-angular-js.html) this post , it might help you